# Create an Angularjs Filter with two file json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

I'm new with angular and I have a problem with a filter. 
I have two different file json like this:

```
    [
        {
            "IdPers": "1067",
            "CognNome": "JANE SMITH",
            "Sex": "F"

        },
        {
            "IdPers": "1093",
            "CognNome": "JOHN SMITH",
            "Sex": "M"

        }

        ]
```

and:
          [

```
        {
            "IdPers": "1067",
            "DescRuol": "Membro"
        },
        {
            "IdPers": "163",
            "DescRuol": "Membro"
        }
        ]
```

I Put a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1xkyxRallRGtj83fSteg?p=preview

I have to create a filter with the field "DescRuol" which is in the file "OutCommissioni.json", the two file have the same field "id". I thought that I can do like a join but I can't make something that works! Thanks for any help

Comment: Is this a possible alternative? Could you rewrite the both files into one?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: ignore this answer - I misunderstood the question. New answer submitted with final details after I worked out what OP really wanted in the comments of this answer.

After fetching data from each file, normalize the difference in properties by assigning the relevant differing field to a common property, and append both sets of data to a single array.

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller("OutAnCtrl", function ($http, $scope) {

    $scope.data = [];

    $http.get('OutAnagrafica.json')
        .success(function (data) {
            data.forEach(function(item) {
              item.name = item.CognNome;
            });
            $scope.data.push.apply($scope.data, data);
        });

     $http.get('OutCommissioni.json')
        .success(function (data) {
          data.forEach(function(item) {
            item.name = item.DescRuol;
          });
          $scope.data.push.apply($scope.data, data);
        });

    $scope.clearBox = function () {
        $scope.filter = "";
    };

});
```

Then finally change your repeater to use the merged data object "data" and the common property name.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="Person in data|filter:filter">
  <td>{{Person.IdPers}}</td>
  <td>{{Person.name}}</td>
  <td>{{Person.Sex}}</td>
</tr>
```

updated example: http://plnkr.co/edit/03rwNY7eLX9i9VCTHz7Z?p=preview

Edit: I probably mis-understood and you probably don't need those properties merged. The key part is just to append both arrays to a single array using Array.push.apply

```
// Create initial array
$scope.data = [];

// Append some arrays
$scope.data.push.apply($scope.data, [1,2,3]);
$scope.data.push.apply($scope.data, [4,5,6]);

// $scope.data will now contain [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Edit: I think this is what you're looking for?
http://plnkr.co/edit/jvyXlpv2iBh2n4pZ1miv?p=preview

```
<label for="DescRuol">DescRuol:</label>
<select data-ng-options="item.IdPers as item.DescRuol for item in OutCommissioni" id="DescRuol" data-ng-model="filter.IdPers" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you're great! Maybe I can't explained very well but what I whant is a filter with the field "DescRuol" and if I select "membro" the filter will result Jane Smith because they have the same ID. I don't know If you're understand, sorry for my english!

Comment: EDIT: i use "unique" filter from ui-utils for delete duplicates in the options but when i have 

          [

            {
                "IdPers": "163",
                "DescRuol": "Presidente"
            },
            {
                "IdPers": "163",
                "DescRuol": "Membro"
            }
            ]

the filter doesn't work well because will filter only one DescRuol. Unique is the problem?? there's s way to make the filter works well?

Comment: Ah ok. I think I understand your problem now.
It sounds like you're trying to pupulate a dropdown select box with non-unique values? If so, it simply doesn't make sense to do that.

Comment: Yes, but for example for the field "sex" it works well.

Comment: That's because you're trying to have two distinctly different options for that field.

A select box is not the right kind of user interface choice for a list of options where the same value may appear multiple times.

Unless you want to concatenate the two options into a single option in the dropdown, both using a single value or something?

e.g. in your example above, have a single option in the select saying "Presidente OR Membro", both with idPers 163?

Comment: I have a long list , and several IdPers have more different DescRuol and what I want is that when I select "Membro" will show the person with idPers = 163 and the same when I select "Presidente" (I hope you have understood) . Is not possible with a select list ?

Comment: It may be - to be honest I'm still having trouble understanding your desired use case. If you could update your plnkr to include a more complete data set that you expect to work with, I may be able to help further.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/MoK0xQJaMXEmFR17qaPv?p=preview I add the person "John Doe" that has the IdPers= 163. In the file OutCommissioni IdPers=163 has "Membro" and "Presidente". I want a select dropdown without duplicate and when I select Membro it will show "John Doe" and the same if I select Presidente.P.S in my project i have more than 2 DescRuol. It's more clear?

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks.
Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/gMvuNny99b8aV66C8GAw?p=preview

If correct, I'll submit the explanation of this as a separate answer for you.

Comment: Yes, I want this but in my project doesn't work well :( Maybe because in my project for eliminate duplicates in the select list i use the filter unique from ui-utils. It's possible?

Comment: I'll submit a new answer summarizing the changes I made - there were a few minor ones which you may not have noticed.

Comment: Sorry but I want to make a clarification. Look at the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yG5gy6QohaBlsAtgppOb?p=preview I add "Jane Doe" that has the Id: 1163. When I select "Membro" will filter jane and john doe but should only filter John Doe. I've understand why but there's a way to avoid it?

Comment: Ah yes - I see. http://plnkr.co/edit/GeQDjP9h6hbAVPacynyI?p=preview
Second paramater to filter forces exact match
just add :true to the end of the filter line.
filter:{...}:true

Comment: Yes, thank you so much you're great. One last thing: Can I delete the duplicates from the select menu? Use ui-unique doesn't working for DescRuol. There's a way or I can't because the filter parameter is the Id??

Comment: Hmmmm - yes but you would have to make a custom filter type and pre-process the data into a format where the two items are combined and ids are an array of ids. Hard to explain through comments here, but after I finish work today I'll update your example to show you what I mean.

Comment: thanks Joel but if you haven't time doesn't matter! You just help me a lot

Comment: I'm sorry but if you have the example would help me so much

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, please ignore my other answer - I mis-understood the question and worked out the details with OP in the comments there.

To have a select box with multiple options using the same value, first thing is to not use the id as the direct value that the select box will use - instead reference the object directly:

```
<select data-ng-options="item as item.DescRuol for item in OutCommissioni" id="DescRuol" data-ng-model="filter.IdPers" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
```

"`item as item.DescRuol`" will use the object itself as the model value, rather than just the id value.

Next, rather than using the "`filter`" object directly in the filter, provide a new object which contains the values you need from your filter object:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="Person in OutAnagrafica|filter:{Sex:filter.Sex,IdPers:filter.IdPers.IdPers}">
```

Working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gMvuNny99b8aV66C8GAw?p=preview